# How can I turn this rotated pole into a custom CRS string?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, netcdf

I have a netCDF file that came with a rotated pole that contains this metadata:

```
float rotated_pole;
  :north_pole_grid_longitude = 0.0f; // float
  :longitude_of_prime_meridian = 0.0f; // float
  :grid_north_pole_latitude = 36.088524f; // float
  :grid_north_pole_longitude = 65.30515f; // float
  :earth_radius = 6371220.0f; // float
  :long_name = "coordinates of the rotated North Pole";
  :grid_mapping_name = "rotated_latitude_longitude";
  :_CoordinateTransformType = "Projection";
  :_CoordinateAxisTypes = "GeoX GeoY";
```

[image]

I'm not quite sure how to approach this.

I've tried a custom proj4 string according to some similar questions I saw:

```
'+proj=ob_tran +o_proj=latlon +o_lon_p=65.30515 +o_lat_p=36.088524 +R=6371220.0'
```

which if converted to wkt using pyproj looks like:

```
'GEOGCRS["unnamed",BASEGEOGCRS["unknown",DATUM["unknown",ELLIPSOID["unknown",6371220,0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8901]]],DERIVINGCONVERSION["unknown",METHOD["PROJ ob_tran o_proj=latlon"],PARAMETER["o_lon_p",65.30515,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9122]]],PARAMETER["o_lat_p",36.088524,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9122]]]],CS[ellipsoidal,2],AXIS["longitude",east,ORDER[1],ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9122]]],AXIS["latitude",north,ORDER[2],ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9122]]]]'
```

also tried:

```
'+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=36.088524 +lon_0=65.30515 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371229 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs'
```

for more context, the grid metadata looks like this and is in lat/lon degrees:

```
grid = {'orientation': 0,
        'origin': (14.1363, -10.345), #x,y
        'nx': 651, #xpixels
        'ny': 564, #ypixels
        'dx': 0.0225, #x resolution
        'dy': 0.0225, #y resolution'}
```

Can anyone help me construct this CRS string? When I export the grid it doesn't seem to line up.